# Uipath string null

Tags: uipath

Does anyone know how to check for an unassigned string in uipath? Uipath seems to crash when an if statement looks for a null string. Not sure how to handle that.  String.empty doesn't seem to work, and if the string is unassigned uipath stops logging and nothing happens.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many different approaches and ideas, but – according to me – what you can do is:

1. Always make sure before to define any variable by default, initialize it with **empty strings("")**. So it will be easy to check it with equal operator as well.
2. The Other approaches you can take in Uipath is based on .Net So u can use it's **Is Nothing**.
3. You can also use .Net **String.IsNullOrEmpty Method (String)** Method.

Answer (score 5):

To check if a string variable is Null, you need to use either an If or Decision activity. The condition of those should be:

```
a is Nothing
```

This will return true if variable a is null and false otherwise

Comment: Hey andra- when I do that uipath stops logging and crashes. I think maybe because it's not nothing or anything so to speak...

Comment: Hi Dan, what version of UiPath are you using? I've tried to reproduce your problem and I am unable. Are you using a String variable or a Generic Value one?

Comment: V8 for uipath. Using a string variable. I fixed it by assigning all my strings as string.empty in the variables window

Answer (score 4):

Best way to check string has value or not -->

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are some of the ways it can be checked.

1.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)
```

2.

```
yourString.Equals("")
```

3.

```
yourString.Equals(Nothing)
```

4.

```
yourString is Nothing
```

5.

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString)
```

There are logical OR, AND and NOT to combine the different checks and they can clubbed together to check the best way to find out blank, null and whitespace string.

Comment: yourString.Equals("") or even yourString.Equals(String.Empty), would produce an exception if yourString is Nothing. Nr5, i.e. String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString), is the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the string using:

```
Convert.ToString(DBNULL.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can check whether String is null with the following Syntax

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("Name_of_the_variable")
```

It will return boolean value

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using the following method in `UiPath`

An If/Decision activity with the condition `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` making use of the `IsNullOrEmpty()` method

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way will be the following:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringVariableName)
```

Comment: This is the same as other answers